# How to create distributed property map with boost library?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, parallel-processing

I am using [this library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/distributed_property_map.html) and I try:

```
typedef vector_property_map<std::size_t> LocalMap;
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Key;
boost::parallel::distributed_property_map< mpi_process_group,LocalMap,Key> dist_map;
```

But fail:

```
mpic++ large_graph.cpp -o large_graph -L/usr/lib/ -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -lboost_graph_parallel -lboost_system -I/usr/include/

/usr/include/boost/property_map/parallel/distributed_property_map.hpp:225:60: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct boost::property_traits<boost::detail::parallel::global_descriptor<long unsigned int> >’
   typedef typename property_traits<StorageMap>::value_type value_type;
                                                            ^
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is `StorageMap`? I only see `LocalMap`.

Comment: It`s third template parameter(in my code is Key).


`template<typename ProcessGroup, typename GlobalMap, typename StorageMap>
    class distributed_property_map`

Answer (score 0):

You may find examples in tests for this library:
https://github.com/mousebird/boost/blob/master/libs/graph_parallel/test/distributed_betweenness_centrality_test.cpp